# In a group chat, is it possible to trigger bot without '@' in Azure Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to create an Azure bot for the Skype channel, and add it to a group conversation. When someone asks a question, I want the bot to be able to reply to the user even if it was not triggered by '@'.

Is there any way to accomplish this in the Bot framework?

Comment: Which channel are you using? Skype?

Comment: Im using Skype channel!

Answer (score 1):

Your bot only receives messages containing its mention, as explained on Skype site:

[image: skype doc]